# How to get sql query from Syncfusion QueryBuilder RuleModel in my Api service?

Tags: blazor, query-builder, syncfusion

I Use Syncfusion query builder in my project.
I want in my blazor client side send json of RuleModel to api server and in api server i deserialize and get sql query from RuleModel.

I try this code:

```
var queryBuilder = new SFQueryBuilder<MyEntity>();
var ruleModel = _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RuleModel>(ruleJson);
var query = queryBuilder.GetSqlFromRules(ruleModel);
```

When run this code i get **NullReferenceException**.

In my project i install **Syncfusion.Blazor.QueryBuilder ver:20.3.0.50**

Comment: can you copy the exact error and the code section where it is giving you null ref error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have prepared the sample based on your requirement. Please refer to the below code snippet and the attached sample. We can’t use the query builder instance like in the below code; if we do, the query builder component does not render properly and throws an error.

Sample link - https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/QueryBuilderSample1558538802

```
var queryBuilder = new SFQueryBuilder<MyEntity>();
var ruleModel = _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RuleModel>(ruleJson);
var query = queryBuilder.GetSqlFromRules(ruleModel);
```

To resolve this issue, we introduce a separate method for converting the rule to an SQL query.

```
[HttpGet("{argument}")]
public void Get(string argument)
{
   var rule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RuleModel>(argument);
   if (rule != null)
   {
       var query = GetSqlString(rule, false, null);
   }
}
```